# Javascript Date Object: startDate < nowDate logic not working correctly due to timezone difference on the client

Tags: javascript

On my server I have multiple events with a "start_date" field, this info is sent to the client with this structure:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Cooking masterclass',
    start_date: '2021-06-21',
    end_date: '2021-06-25',
}
```

When I receive the list of events on my client I want to classify them on 2 categories: Ongoing and Upcoming, so my code looks something like this

```
const ongoingEvents = [], upcomingEvents = []

for (const event of allEvents) {
    const startDate = new Date(Date.parse(event.start_date))
    const nowDate = new Date()

    if (startDate < nowDate) {
        ongoingEvents.push(event)
    } else {
        upcomingEvents.push(event)
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I check what "startDate" and "nowDate" are it looks like this. As you can see the start date doesnt show Jun 21st but Jun 20 at 5pm instead.

```
startDate: Sun Jun 20 2021 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
nowDate:   Sun Jun 20 2021 18:36:51 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

So for example even though the event starts on the 21st, on the 20th at 6:36pm it will show that the event already started in the "Ongoing" section because 6:36pm is later than 5:00pm.

What is the best way of deal with this issue?

Another issue I'm having is that I want to show in my client the Start Date of the event in this format:

```
Start Date: June 21
```

But when I use the startDate variable to format into a string like this:

```
const startString = startDate.toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'short', day: 'numeric' })
const endString  = endDate.toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'short', day: 'numeric' })
```

I get:

```
Start Date: June 20
```

Probably is the same solution for both issues. I hope someone can guide me to the right solution.
Thanks!

Comment: Curiously what time zone are you in b/c I am getting the exptected result over here...

Comment: The problem is `new Date(Date.parse(event.start_date))`. You'll need to specify a timezone there, otherwise it assumes UTC (though not in some old browsers).

Comment: I am on PST timezone which is UTC -7h, this is why when the client reads start date on the 21st it converts it to my PST time zone which is 20th at 5pm

Comment: So you want the dates in the event objects sent by your server always be interpreted in UTC-7, regardless where the client is? If so, use `new Date(event.start_date+"T00:00-07:00")`.

Comment: I believe this would work if all the clients where in PST time. I would have to make it dynamic so it grabs the time offset of the client right?

Comment: To directly answer your question, the best way to deal with this issue is to store UTC dates/times on your server and provide them to your javascript in ISO 8601 format. For any specific timezone shifting use a library like date-fns or luxon to help you.

Comment: This is already what I'm doing, my server stores times in UTC and the start_date: '2021-06-21', is already in ISO 8601 format.